# Snowflake Python connector not connecting with AWS glue python shell

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I'm trying to connect to snowflake using Glue python shell. I followed the following documentation https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-create-a-AWS-Glue-Job-in-Python-Shell-using-Wheel-and-Egg-files.

But python shell is not able to import snowflake library. Could any point me where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with the error that you encountered? Also confirm if the role used for Glue job has read access to the snowflake package on S3 ?

Comment: The job fails at 'import snowflake' it is not able to find a snowflake package. I tried with another python package by creating .whl and.egg and also custom packages that are getting imported fine in AWS glue python shell job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .whl or .egg file for this purpose.
Please follow my blog.I have documented all the steps :

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/AWS-Glue-Job-in-Python-Shell-using-Wheel-and-Egg-files

Comment: page not found...